# iOS - Stuck on numberOfRowsInSection: with multiple sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmanagedobject, sections

I need some help with `numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Actually, I'm looking for a more dynamic way to set the number of rows. Since in my app it's possible to create `sections` (as many as you want, they are stored as NSMutableArray by NSUserDafults) I think that something like that would be too hard-coded and therefore totally wrong as I cannot know how many sections the user will create.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return ...
    }
    if (section == n) {
        return ...
    }        
}
```

Then, I'm struggling how I can display `NSManagedObject` in these sections. I mean, when the user create that `NSManagedObject`, he sets the its **section property**. I would like that the `NSManagedObject` will be displayed in the right `section`.

**P.S.** The `NSManagedObjects` are stored in a `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your `NSMutableArray` in which you keep your `NSManagedObjects` using `NSPredicate` to return all objects which are in particular section. I don't know the type of you `section property` but lets assume that it is `NSInteger` so that we can easily use section param from

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

then inside this method you can filter `myArray` and count it's objects:

```
[[self.myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"section == %d",section]] count];
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do that would be to put the managed objects for each section into separate arrays, then create an array of those arrays.

So if you divided them up like so:

```
NSArray *sections - @[@[obj1, obj2, obj3],
                      @[obj4, obj5, obj6],
                      ...];
```

You could implement `numberOfRowsInSection` as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sections[section] count];
}
```